# How to persist state from a class into a separate SwiftUI view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am having problems persisting a class's state into a SwiftUI struct's view.

I have a class that acts as a controller, defined in one file, and a SwiftUI view that is supposed to change according to properties in that controller.

I've defined these files as such:

ClockController.swift

```
class ClockController:ObservableObject {
    @Binding var isAM:Bool

    init(){
        self.isAM = false
    }

    func toggleAMPM(){
        self.isAM = !self.isAM
    }

}
```

and TestUI.swift

```
struct TestUI:View{
    @ObservedObject var clockController:ClockController = ClockController()


    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.clockController.toggleAMPM()
        }){
            Text("Toggle")
            }
        Text(self.clockController.isAM ? "AM" : "PM")
    }
}
```

I want the TestUI to change/re-render every time the self.clockController.isAM variable changes (when the toggle button is pressed), which is why I have made ClockController an ObservableObject and added the @Binding keyword to the isAM property. However, I keep getting the following errors with this setup on ClockController's initializer method:

`'self' used in property access 'isAM' before all stored properties are initialized` and `Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties`

How can I get my TestUI to bind on ClockController's isAM variable?

Comment: You code does not compile and is full of typos. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)

Comment: I apologize, I had to get creative while anonymizing the example. It compiles now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all! I've fixed the problem myself. I needed to remove the @Binding keyword from ClockController's isAM property and change it to `@Published`. That did the trick.

Kudo's to YouTube and this video: https://youtu.be/-yjKAb0Pj60?t=919